# how to apply group by clause in core data

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, core-data

i am implementing tableview and  i want to show class name in the section of tableview, and i am trying to fetching 
classes values from database implemented using core data, and i want to fetch data using group by clause on classname this is my code

```
   AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
    //create managed object context
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];


    NSFetchRequest* fetch = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Boking_Detail"];
    NSEntityDescription* entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Boking_Detail"
                                              inManagedObjectContext:context];
    NSAttributeDescription* clsName = [entity.attributesByName objectForKey:@"classname"];
    NSAttributeDescription* clsDate = [entity.attributesByName objectForKey:@"classdate"];
    NSAttributeDescription* startTime = [entity.attributesByName objectForKey:@"starttime"];
    NSAttributeDescription* endTime = [entity.attributesByName objectForKey:@"endtime"];

    NSExpressionDescription *expressionDescription = [[NSExpressionDescription alloc] init];
    [expressionDescription setName: @"count"];
   // [expressionDescription setExpression: countExpression];
    [expressionDescription setExpressionResultType: NSInteger32AttributeType];
    [fetch setPropertiesToFetch:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:clsName,clsDate,startTime,endTime, expressionDescription, nil]];
    [fetch setPropertiesToGroupBy:[NSArray arrayWithObject:clsName]];
    [fetch setResultType:NSDictionaryResultType];
    NSError* error = nil;
    NSArray *results = [context executeFetchRequest:fetch  error:&error];

    NSLog(@"result array count %i",results.count);
     NSLog(@"result array values %@",results);
```

and i am getting this error

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'SELECT clauses in queries with GROUP BY components can only contain properties named in the GROUP BY or aggregate functions ((<NSAttributeDescription: 0xc288680>), name classdate, isOptional 1, isTransient 0, entity Boking_Detail, renamingIdentifier classdate, validation predicates (
), warnings (
), versionHashModifier (null)
 userInfo {
}, attributeType 700 , attributeValueClassName NSString, defaultValue (null) is not in the GROUP BY)'
*** First throw call stack:
```

Comment: Why are you getting dictionary results?  Seems like you are fighting the framework here.

Answer (score 8):

You also have to add your other attributes from `propertiesToFetch` to the group by clause except for the expression:

```
[fetch setPropertiesToGroupBy:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:clsName, clsDate, startTime, endTime, nil]];
```

Comment: but i just want to group record on classname

Comment: A valid SQL statement, this is what Core Data finally generates for you, needs all non-aggregated attributes you have in your select clause also in the group by clause: http://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html#resultset